# Unable to Edit Field-type in Engine-Index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created an Elasticsearch Index following this guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/elasticsearch-engines-create.html.

In the new Index Engine, I'm trying to change the field type in the Engine Schema but the drop-down box that changes it is disabled.

[image]

Is there a way to change the field type of an Engine Index?

I tried going through the process of create the Engine Index again by follow the guide I post but I was still getting the same results.